# Android Maps API Example not working?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I tried the official example code from google's API website:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Neither this nor their SDK code is compiling without errors..

For the easy example, it says *"Error inflating class fragment"*

I saw a lot of people do *"MainActivity expands Fragment"* but it doesn't in this example so i wanted to try this way.

The also don't mention you have to add an *"Activity"* Tag in your manifest.. how can they forget ?

I used

- API17 in Eclipse
- Galaxy S2 (4.0.4) as a test device.

Thanks for any suggestions

Edit:
I don't know why it's working now, but it is..
The problem was, the library was not correctly referenced, also i had to make these settings in the "Project Properties", i simply had to 'tick' all of them:

(can't post screenshot)

Comment: Can you please post your main.xml and MainActivity.java code? The example you pointed to doesn't use fragments at all.

Comment: post your code here along with manifest.xml

Comment: @siboney you can answer your own question which is even encouraged http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly install the "google play services library" and the "android-support-v4.jar" as described in the google example